# Read data from xlsx using JAVA apache poi fails to read the last cell of a row

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

Below is the code to read data from 9 excel cells.

Excel data format is at the end of code.
It has two rows.
It never reads the last cells data,tried all the combinations

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class Exceldata {
public static XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
public static XSSFSheet sheet = null;
public static XSSFRow row = null;
public static XSSFCell cell = null;
public static  String[] col_name= new String[9];
public static String[][] user_data=new String[2][9];

public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
 File src= new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Testdata.xlsx");
 FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);
 XSSFWorkbook book= new XSSFWorkbook(fis);         
 XSSFSheet sheet_userdata= book.getSheet("UserDetails");          
 for(int p=0;p<book.getNumberOfSheets();p++) 
 {
  System.out.println("Sheet Name is : "+ book.getSheetName(p));
  }
 row=sheet_userdata.getRow(0);
 for(int j =0;j<9;j++) 
 {
  cell=row.getCell(j);
  col_name[j]=String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
  System.out.println(col_name[j]);
  }
   //Read  data from cells
  for(int i=0;i<sheet_userdata.getLastRowNum();i++)
  {
  row=sheet_userdata.getRow(i+1);
  for(int k=0;k<9;k++) 
{
  if((cell=row.getCell(k))!= null) 
 {
  switch(cell.getCellType())
{
 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
   if(k==1) 
 {
 user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
 System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
 }else if(k==2)
{
 user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
 System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
}
 else if(k==3) 
{
 user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
 System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
}
else if(k==5) 
{
 user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
 System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
 }
else if(k==6) 
{
 user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
 System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
 }
else if(k==7) 
{
 user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf(cell.getStringCellValue());
 System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
 }
 else if(k==8) 
{
  user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf((cell.getStringCellValue()));
System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");
System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
}
break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
 if(k==0) 
{
 user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf((long)(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
 System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");                                        
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);                                                                              
 }
else if(k==4) 
{
 user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf((long)(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
 System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
 }
break;
 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
user_data[i][k]=cell.getStringCellValue();
System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
 break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
 //user_data[i][k]="";
if(k==8) 
{
 user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf((cell.getStringCellValue()));
 System.out.println(col_name[k]+" is : ");
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
}
break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
  user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf(cell.getCellFormula());
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
 break;
 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
user_data[i][k]=String.valueOf(cell.getErrorCellString());
 System.out.println(user_data[i][k]);
 break;
}
}
}
}
}catch(Exception e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
                                                            
                                            
 }

 }
```

XLS sheet data has two rows like this( NOte : Status cell is empty)

S.No.|  ID     |First Name |Last Name  |Contact number |Email id   |Usermode    |channel   |Status
1     test@test.com Ram       singh       45455666        xyz@test.com Password     XYZ       empty cell

Comment: For the first option,It gives error at this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it gives a NULL pointer exception when a cell is blank or empty or no values in  it when using getcell(int k);,So the solution is before the if((cell=row.getCell(k))!=null) add a line to convert the null to blank like this
cell=row.getcell(k,row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1
you have checked cell null condition but not "" this condition.There might be chances that if you have added data manually to excel sheet that cell is not BLANK and have some space etc. Try to Add this

```
if((row.getCell(k))!= ""){
//now check column is 8
if(k==8)
```

Option 2
That cell type might be UNKNOWN so add this case as well

```
case Cell.CellType _NONE
```

Option 3
Your are expecting that cell type as blank but it could be either numeric or string so try to add K==8 condition in both of this switch case or find out specific type of that cell first.

Comment: For the first option,It gives error at this line  if((cell=row.getCell(k))!= null) ,so when condition if((cell=row.getCell(k))!= "") is added in OR to it ,it gives compilation error as XSSFCell and string incomparable strings. When K becomes 8 ,it just stops at this line  if((cell=row.getCell(k))!= null) and starts executing for the next row.I have added K==8 in both switch conditions but when K=8 ,it just comes at line  if((cell=row.getCell(k))!= null) and then skips that.